# Is ArrayList<String> any special from ArrayList containing other types in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Code below run on my hotspot JVM and I got *"a"* as output.

```
ArrayList<Method> list = new ArrayList<>();
Method method = list.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("add", Object.class);
method.invoke(list, "a");
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

But a `ClassCastException` occured after running the below code:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
Method method1 = list1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("add", Object.class);
method1.invoke(list1, 1); // or replaced with method1.invoke(list1, new int[]{1});
System.out.println(list1.get(0));
```

What's wrong with the second code?
Is `ArrayList<String>` any special?

Comment: Last two lines in the second snippet should probably use `list1` instead of `list`?

Comment: @maloomeister Sorry about that. But the exception is not caused by this reason. Is there the same problem on your jvm?

Comment: There's nothing special. The first case is invoking `PrintStream.println(Object)` (which is the most specific method that can be invoked for a `Method`, the expected type of `list.get(0)`, and which doesn't need a cast to make sure it is an `Object`); the second cast is invoking `PrintStream.println(String)` (which is the most specific method that can be invoked for a `String`, the expected type of `list.get(0)`, but since raw `list.get(0)` returns an `Object`, a cast to `String` is required).

Comment: For the people who voted to close as not reproducible: https://ideone.com/b2HlOQ. This question isn't a typo, either, it's observing a consequence of the way generics are implemented, and their interaction with method invocation rules.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for your answer sincerely! I have not known the `println(Object)` before. There were some typos when I posted the question as @maloomeister said above. And I corrected it after noticed. That's why the question was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about `ArrayList<String>`. It's simply how generics and method invocation expressions interact in the language. What you are observing is as a result of there being overloads of `PrintStream.println` for both `Object` and `String` parameters.

The TL;DR: is that the former case invokes `PrintStream.println(Object)`; the latter cast invokes `PrintStream.println(String)`, for which the compiler inserts a cast because the `String` is coming from a list expected to contain `String`s only.

---

Generics are simply compiler-inserted casts. When the compiler sees that a method returns a `E` (e.g. `ArrayList<E>::get(int)`), it thinks that the result of that method can be safely cast to `E` (because it is an `E`, a subclass of `E`, or null).

In order to use that result as an `E`, though, it has to cast the result to `E`, because the result of `get` is an `Object`, because of type erasure.

So, when you write things like:

```
List<String> list = ...
String s = list.get(0);
list.get(0).toString();
System.out.println("" + list.get(0));
```

the compiler will insert casts, and so the code which is actually executed looks like:

```
List<String> list = ...
String s = (String) list.get(0);
((String) list.get(0)).toString();
System.out.println("" + (String) list.get(0));
```

which is harder to read; but you don't need the explicit casts, because the compiler knows to insert them for you, based on the fact that `list` is a `List<String>`.

---

When you invoke a method, like `System.out.println`, the compiler goes through quite a complicated process to determine which  method to invoke.

In this case, it looks at the `PrintStream` class, and finds all of the overloads of the method `println`; then it narrows these down to the ones which *could* be invoked for the given arguments; then it picks which of the potential matches is most specific.

Again, "most specific" is rather complicated, but it is summarised as *a method is more specific if any valid parameters can also be passed to a less specific method, but not vice versa*.

```
class Foo {
  static void foo(String str) {}
  static void foo(Object str) {}
}
```

So, `foo(String)` is more specific than `foo(Object)`, because all `String`s are `Object`, but not all `Object`s are `String`s.

So, when you're invoking `foo(something)` and `something` is expected to be a `String`, `foo(String)` is invoked, even though `foo(Object)` could also be invoked; if it's any other kind of object, `foo(Object)` is invoked, because not-`String`s can't be passed to `foo(String)`.

---

Enough theory, let's look at this specific example:

```
ArrayList<Method> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

The overload of `PrintStream.println` which is most specific for this invocation is `PrintStream.println(Object)`. The raw `list.get(0)` call returns an Object, so no cast needs to be inserted by the compiler to make it compatible.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

Hence, there is no problem if `list.get(0)` returns something that isn't a `Method`.

The overload of `PrintStream.println` which is most specific for this invocation is `PrintStream.println(String)`. The raw `list.get(0)` call returns an Object, so a cast to `String` needs to be inserted by the compiler to make it compatible.

In fact, the code executed is effectively:

```
System.out.println((String) list.get(0));
```

Hence, there *is* problem if `list.get(0)` returns something that isn't a `String`: you will get a `ClassCastException`, as you found.

The important thing to point out here is that this happens because of what the compiler *expects* the types to be, because of the type information it has at its disposal. These are reasonable expectations that are safe if you haven't done type-unsafe things (like adding to the list reflectively); but the protections offered by the compiler are somewhat trivial to work around.

For this reason, you should pay careful attention to ensure that what you are doing really *is* type-safe still, even when you are working behind the safety guard of the compiler.